# Multiple matches nearest roll join with data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two `data.table` that I want to merge based on two columns. One on exact match (`station`) and the other on the nearest value (`depth_m`).

```r
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.table(
  station = "a",
  depth_m = 1
)

df2 <- data.table(
  station = c("a", "a", "b"),
  depth_m = c(1.1, 1.1, 2),
  wavelength = c(300, 350, 300),
  bbp = c(0.0012, 0.0013, 0.0014)
)

df1
#>    station depth_m
#> 1:       a       1
df2
#>    station depth_m wavelength    bbp
#> 1:       a     1.1        300 0.0012
#> 2:       a     1.1        350 0.0013
#> 3:       b     2.0        300 0.0014
```

To do it so, I am using `roll = "nearest"` as follow:

```r
df2[df1, on = .(station, depth_m), roll = "nearest"]
#>    station depth_m wavelength    bbp
#> 1:       a       1        300 0.0012
```

However, I would also get the row of `df2` where `wavelength == 350` so the result is:

```r
data.table(
  station = c("a", "a"),
  depth = c(1, 1),
  wavelength = c(300, 305),
  bbp = c(0.0012, 0.0013)
)
#>    station depth wavelength    bbp
#> 1:       a     1        300 0.0012
#> 2:       a     1        305 0.0013
```

Hence, I have tried to use `mult = "all"` without sucess:

```r
df2[df1, on = .(station, depth_m), roll = "nearest", mult = "all"]
#>    station depth_m wavelength    bbp
#> 1:       a       1        300 0.0012
```

Any help is appreciated.

<sup>Created on 2021-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In theory you should be able to use `mult = "all"`. However, there are two open issues on this topic which suggests that currently this doesn't work as expected. In [with floats, roll="nearest", mult="all" erroneously gives only a single match](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2444) a workaround was suggested, where the join column was converted to integer, which then returned the correct number of rows.

In a follow-up issue, using a later version `data.table` version ([Join on integers, roll = "nearest" and mult = "all" erroneously gives only a single match](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4382)), the workaround no longer worked.

Comment: The issue has been opened for almost 1 year now. I hope this gets fixed. Thank you for your answers.